# Дышите не дышите, мышите не мышите!

Tags: запятые, дефис

«Дышите не дышите, мышите не мышите».

Как такого плана глаголы писать? С тире, с запятой (очень не склоняюсь), с дефисом (навряд ли)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно так: *дышите не дышите, мышите не мышите*.

[**Запятая при повторяющихся словах**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105) (Розенталь):

> 4. Запятая не ставится:
>    **1)** между двумя повторяющимися словами, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием ***не,*** если сочетание этих слов образует смысловое целое, выражающее неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо: ***Страшно не страшно,** а на душе как-то строго* (Леск.)...

**Дополнение после комментариев**

Посмотрел сейчас фрагмент из "Кота Леопольда". Там, конечно, ирония, и "Пилюлькин" говорит почти скороговоркой, между парными глаголами не делая паузы.

Вообще, в таком случае можно ставить запятые, точки или многоточие:

*Ничего, стетоскопом, дышите, не дышите, повернитесь, разведите руки.* [А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)]

*С упоением лечила меня, выслушивала, выстукивала, говорила «дышите», «не дышите», делала уколы, капала в нос ― понарошку, но из настоящей пипетки.* [А. И. Пантелеев. Наша Маша (1966)]

А заголовок статьи о кондиционерах должен отражать главный смысл содержания, поэтому трудно сказать, что там поставить. Может и тире подойти:

*Дышите – не дышите. Мышите – не мышите.* (Только вот поймёт ли читатель, на какой слог ставить ударение?)

Comment: Ну здесь противопоставление..... у Вас..

Comment: @flossyU   Тогда огласите весь список, пожалуйста! :)  Пишите всегда окружающие предложения и желательно смысл, который вкладывается во фразу. Конечно, может быть и с запятой, когда это произносит врач. И с точкой.

Comment: Ну фразу из кота Леопольда знаете ведь?! Дышите и мышите...) Вот в том контексте.... Это заголовок с статье о кондиционерах (первая часть о дыхании).... А вообще, где-то есть описание таких вот глаголов...повторяющихся...